# Show/Hide Rows Depending on Dropdown Selection

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first time I'm working with Macros.
I've created a dropdown in B2 with a "Yes" and "No" options.

- If User selects "Yes", Row 10 Shows / Row 11 Hides
- If User Selects "No", Row 11 Shows / Row 10 Hides

I used this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
If Range("B2") = Yes Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B2") = No Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End If
End Sub
```

I Created a new Module in **Sheet1**, and put it there. I saved the excel as a *Macro Enabled Tamplate*, however nothing happens when I change the dropdown.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Range("B2") = "Yes" Then
```

and similarly with the "No " option

Comment: Thanks, I have just figured it out :). Josie, is there a way to hide a row assigning a variable name to it? I noticed that if I have a macro script insert a new row, then `Rows("10:10")` is no longer the right row - since all the contend has been moved down.

Comment: yes you can name a cell in row 10 and then use `range("range_name").EntireRow.Hidden = False` for instance

Comment: Thanks! I think I aalmost got it. Right now, I'm getting a RUNTIME Error 1004. `Method of 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' Failed`. Here's the code I use: http://jsfiddle.net/tG5X3/

Comment: the code that assigns the names should specify the sheet that Rows belongs to-I'm assuming it's the same one your change event code is in

Answer (score 4):

Do yourself a huge favor and get in the habit of writing `Option Explicit` at the top of every module of VBA code you write.

I have added comments as well explaining your needed revisions.

```
'this requires you to dimension all variables
'when you used '= yes' VBA thought you were saying
'the same as, = aVariable
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        If Range("B2").Value = "Yes" Then
            'You can reference the row directly on the same sheet
            'and do not need ActiveSheet
            Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("B2").Value = "No" Then
            Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Also be aware this is only using "Yes" - using "yes" or "YES" will cause problems. You can use the `UCase` method as follows if you want to avoid these situations in the future:

```
        If UCase(Range("B2").Value) = "YES" Then
```